# Show textbox scrolled to the top without highlighted text on UserForm.Show

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I know how to show a textbox scrolled to the top on a `UserForm.Show` event, however that involves the method `SetFocus` and if I set the focus, it automatically highlights the text which I do not want. I'm using a userform to show a message because my messages are too long for a MsgBox. Is there a way to prevent it from auto-selecting the text while still having the box scrolled to the top upon `.Show`? This scrolls to the top but still selects the text despite 0 values:

```
Messages.MessageBox.SetFocus
Messages.MessageBox.SelStart = 0
Messages.MessageBox.SelLength = 0
```

`Messages.MessageBox.TabStop = False` is so close to working, but the fact that you can scroll isn't obvious (scroll bars only appear when you click in the textbox) and when you click in the textbox it auto scrolls to the bottom again.

If there is no way around this, is there a better solution that a UserForm for what I am trying to do (show long messages)? I cannot use a label instead of a textbox either, the messages exceed the character limit for the `.Caption` property.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it but I'm not going to accept this as the true correct answer because I don't think it would solve everyone's problem. I needed to allow my users to still edit the spreadsheet while the userform was open, so when I set `Messages.Show vbModeless` it fixed everything. None of the text was selected, the scroll bars were visible, and it was scrolled to the top. I have a feeling it's because the focus technically isn't specifically on the userform anymore, so it didn't highlight the text. If you need to make sure nobody messes with the spreadsheet while the userform is open though, this will not solve the problem for you.

Full code for example:

```
Sub ValidateData()
    'Do all your stuff
    Call Messages_Initialize(msgDict)
    Messages.Show vbModeless
End Sub

Sub Messages_Initialize(msgs As Dictionary)
    Dim msgString As String
    If Not msgs.Exists("success") Then
        msgString = "The cells highlighted in red contain invalid values. Please fix before attempting to validate them again."
        msgItems = msgs.Items
        For i = 0 To msgs.Count - 1
            msgString = msgString + vbNewLine + vbNewLine + msgItems(i)
        Next i
    Else
        msgString = msgs("success")
    End If
    Messages.MessageBox.Text = msgString
    Messages.MessageBox.MultiLine = True
    Messages.MessageBox.Locked = True
    Messages.MessageBox.WordWrap = True
    Messages.MessageBox.SetFocus
    Messages.MessageBox.CurLine = 0
End Sub
```